# How can I restart a fragment that has been created from the activity in viewpager2?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

How can I restart fragment from activity in a viewpager2.I tried methods like `notifyDataSetChanged()` `notifyItemChanged(0)`. But didn't work.

**ViewPagerAdapter.kt**

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(
    fragmentManager : FragmentManager,
    var fragments : MutableList<Fragment>,
    lifecycle : Lifecycle
) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {
    override fun getItemCount() : Int {
        return fragments.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position : Int) : Fragment {
        return fragments[position]
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
private val tabsArray = arrayOf("Test1", "Test2")


...
fragmentPagerAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter(
            supportFragmentManager,
            fragments,
            lifecycle
        )
        viewPager.adapter = fragmentPagerAdapter

        TabLayoutMediator(tabs, viewPager) {tab, position ->
            tab.text = tabsArray[position]
        }.attach()
...
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `restart`? Do you want to create a new instance again of the fragment?

Comment: No, I want to reload fragment in activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below. source:[link](https://medium.com/bazaar-tech/dynamically-update-refresh-reload-viewpager2-fragments-588fcbd6f859)

**MainActivity.kt**

```
...
viewPagerAdapter.refreshFragment(1, ForthFragment())
...
```

**FragmentAdapter.kt**

```
...
fun refreshFragment(index: Int, fragment: Fragment) {
        fragments[index] = fragment
        notifyItemChanged(index)
    }

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return fragments[position].hashCode().toLong()
    }

    override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean {
        return fragments.find { it.hashCode().toLong() == itemId } != null
    }

...
```

Comment: This will create a new `instance` of the Fragment & not `reload` as to what the OP replied to my comment.